# python regex look around enigma

Tags: python, regex

**EDITED QUESTION WITH A MORE COMPREHENSIVE STRING EXAMPLE**

Trying to find a regex that can extract only the numerical values from the below sample text if they are followed by the phrase `'PLD GLTY'`. I have added all the permutations of this content I could dig out of my data.  Here they are.

'INDICT 2903.04.A INVOLUNTARY PLD GLTY @ TRL JURY', 'INDICT 2903.01.B AGGRAVATED NOLLE', 'INDICT 2911.01 ROBBERY PLD GLTY @ TRL JURY', 'INDICT 2905.01.A(2) NOLLE', 'INDICT 2903.02.B NOLLE', 'INDICT 2911.02.A(2) NOLLE', 'INDICT 2903.111.A(1) FELONIOUS ASSAULT PLD GLTY', 'INDICT 2913.05 ROBBERY PLD GLTY @ TRL JURY', 'INDICT 2923.13.A(3) HAVING WEAPONS WHILE UNDER DISABILITY PLD GLTY'

**Expected result** (ideally into a python list)

['2903.04', '2911.01', '2903.111', '2913.05', '2923.13']

**SAMPLES THAT WORK PARTIALLY**

Sample that works mostly

```
29..\...+(?=PLD GLTY)
```

Works better but still capturing too much

```
\d{4}\.\d{2}(.*PLD GLTY)
```

Almost there, still not quite getting there

```
(\d{4}\.\d{2}\d?)(.*PLD GLTY)
```

The goal is to take the above text which is in a pandas df column and extract from that text only the numerical statutes that for which the defendant plead guilty.

Thanks for your help all you regex wizards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. I just modified your lookahead example to add a non-greedy `.*` and some fine tweaks:

```
(\d{4}\.\d{2,3}).*?(?=PLD GLTY)
```

**Code**:

```
import re

str = 'This is statute 2913.42 and defendant PLD GLTY, This is statute 2913.405 and defendant at pre-trial PLD GLTY, This is statute 2913.44 without any plea of guilt'

print(re.findall(r'(\d{4}\.\d{2,3}).*?(?=PLD GLTY)', str))
# ['2913.42', '2913.405']
```

`d{2}\d?` is better written as `\d{2,3}` (digits always appear 2 or 3 times).

[`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) is a built-in in Python, so it is advised to not use it as variable name, custom function name or whatever, though I used here to match your code.

Comment: I'd recommend to let OP know that it is not a good idea to use `str` as a variable name in Python.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sure, will add straightaway.

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase your problem as:

```
str = 'This is statute 2913.42 and defendant PLD GLTY, This is statute 2913.405 and defendant at pre-trial PLD GLTY, This is statute 2913.44 without any plea of guilt'
matches = re.findall(r'\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^\d]+\bPLD GLTY)', str)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['2913.42', '2913.405']
```

The regex logic says to find every decimal with the property that we can look forward *without* seeing another number, and find the text `PLD GLTY` somewhere later in the string.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The "without seeing another number" bit is crucial here. Yours is currently the only answer that achieves this, when given a more discriminating test string. (See my comment which, for reasons of length, I have needed to post as an "answer".)

Answer (score 0):

*(This is intended as an extended **comment** rather than an answer. Please don't vote on it, or I may have to remove it again.)*

The example string given in the question is not sufficient to test whether the solutions given will ensure that only the *last* number before any occurrence of `PLD GLTY` is included in the output.

With this string:

```
str = "This is statute 2913.42 and defendant PLD GLTY, This is statute 2913.44 without any plea of guilt, This is statute 2913.405 and defendant at pre-trial PLD GLTY"
```

Obviously you would want it to return: `['2913.42', '2913.405']`.

At time of writing, there are three answers, only *one* of which passes this test, although *all three* of them pass using the test string given in the question.

Comment: Good point.  I tested the above and it worked flawlessly, except this string, it mistakenly identified the first statute as one which precedes a PLD GLTY when it doesn't.  I looked at the code and cannot figure out why this string causes an error.   'INDICT 2921.12.A(1) TAMPERING WITH EVIDENCE NOLLE', 'INDICT 2925.11.A DRUG POSSESSION PLD GLTY- N/C - IND @ P/T', 'INDICT 2925.11.A DRUG POSSESSION NOLLE']

Comment: The criticism above about my example not being comprehensive enough and mistakenly using "str" as a variable name all well taken.   @TimBiegelsen's answer led to some mistakes however, only because I didn't provide a sufficiently comprehensive string example.  Here is one of the strings that resulted in errant output with Tim's response.  'INDICT 2921.12.A(1) ATTEMPTED, TAMPERING WITH EVIDENCE PLD GLTY- N/C LIO-AMEND @ P/T', 'INDICT 2925.11.A DRUG POSSESSION PLD GLTY- N/C - IND @ P/T'].  That A(1) part after the statute caused the regex to produce the statute number and a number "1" too.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Best thing would be if you can put into the question itself all the example strings that are likely to be necessary to validate correct behaviour, and then afterwards let me know and I can delete my comment ("answer") which will serve no further purpose once you have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Good idea.  Will do that shortly.